# How to capture the `debug` output from a task into a logfile?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to capture the status `HAProxy` running on hosts.

I cannot figure out how to capture the `debug` output from a task into a logfile as this shows the host name and status.

**Output**

```yaml
"haproxystatus.results.0.status.SubState": "dead",
"item": "hostnamedisplayedhere",
"my_idx": 0
```

No errors as such, cannot workout how to print/capture the debug into a logfile.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is almost no description what you really try to achieve, because there are several different possibilities for gathering and logging a service status.

Anyway, regarding

> ***How to capture the `debug` output from a task into a logfile?***

such functionality is already available in Ansible in example with the [`log_play` callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html) and one approach could be the following ...

With an `ansible.cfg`

```ini
[default]
stdout_callback         = yaml
callback_whitelist      = log_plays

[callback_log_plays]
log_folder              = /tmp/ansible/hosts
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "Debug output"
```

will result into an `stdout` of

```yaml
PLAY [test] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: Hello world!

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
test.example.com  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

and a log file

```bash
~/test$ ll /tmp/ansible/hosts/
total 52
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users   314 Oct 14 12:45 test.example.com
```

with content

```bash
~/test$ cat /tmp/ansible/hosts/test.example.com
Oct 14 2023 12:45:15 - log_plays.yml -  - debug - OK - {"msg": "Debug output", "changed": false, "_ansible_verbose_always": true, "_ansible_no_log": false}
```

For further possibilities the Use Case and question need to be more specific, ideally with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).